# Lowest scope to get user Timezone information

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-app-verification

We are trying to get access to the Timezone of the user or of his/her primary calendar.

What is the lowest scope in order to do this? Currently we are using `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"`

If we check the main [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#calendar) documentation it says.

> See the title, description, default time zone, and other properties of Google calendars you have access to

The issue is that it is a sensitive scope and we would rather use a non-sensitive scope. Is there a way to do that?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the docs for [calendars.get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendars/get) you will see that you need to use one of the following scopes

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

The lowest scope that gives the lest amount of access will be the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly`  this scope will give you the ability to read everything on a users account but not make any changes.

You only have two options if you want to use the calendar.get method.  either the full read scope or the read only scope.   You will need to accept that this is a sensitive scope.

Comment: Hello DaImTo, thank you for your answer. Given that a calendar Timezone did not seem to me to be such a sensitive information (unlike the title and description, for instance), I was wondering whether there was another way without using a sensitive scope. For instance I would have assumed that this would be available in a non-sensitive scope like ./auth/calendar.events.freebusy, but I guess your answer confirmed that it is not currently the case and that it is necessary to use a sensitive scope. If my understanding is incorrect please let me know. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: Scopes are not that limiting. You are getting read access to all of the users calendar account not just the time zone the whole thing.  There is no way to get just access to the timezone.   It would be nice if you could but thats not how scopes work.